# CompletableFuture.allOf().get() does not run in a unit test

Tags: java, junit

I have a method which asynchronously builds several DTOs. It works well in general use so I'm trying to write some unit tests for it. The method looks like:

```java
    public List<SurgeClientDto> clientLeaderboard(@RequestBody List<String> accountIds) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        List<SurgeClientDto> surgeClients = new ArrayList<>(accountIds.size());

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String accountId : accountIds) {
            futures.add(
                  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                      buildSurgeClientDto(surgeClients, accountId);
                  }, executor)
            );
        }

        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).get();

        log.info("Time taken: {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

        return surgeClients;
    }
```

and my test looks like:

```java
    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void testGetLeaderboard() throws Exception {
        // Given
        final List<String> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
        final String accountOne = "ABCDE";
        final String accountTwo = "ZYXWV";
        final String accountThree = "FAKE!";
        final String clientForename = "John";
        final String clientSurname = "Smith";

        ClientDetailsCursorResult validOne = ClientDetailsCursorResult.builder()
              .accountId(accountOne)
              .forename(clientForename)
              .surname(clientSurname)
              .build();
        ClientDetailsCursorResult validTwo = ClientDetailsCursorResult.builder()
              .accountId(accountTwo)
              .forename(clientForename)
              .surname(clientSurname)
              .build();

        BalanceDetailsDto validBalanceDetailsDto = new BalanceDetailsDto();
        validBalanceDetailsDto.setAvailableToWithdraw(100d);
        validBalanceDetailsDto.setAvailableBalance(100d);

        accounts.add(accountOne);
        accounts.add(accountTwo);
        accounts.add(accountThree);

        // When
        when(accountMaintenanceRestClient.getAccount(accountOne)).thenReturn(accountDTO());
        when(accountMaintenanceRestClient.getAccount(accountTwo)).thenReturn(accountDTO());
        when(accountMaintenanceRestClient.getAccount(accountThree)).thenReturn(null);

        when(clientDetailsJdbc.getClientAccounts(accountOne)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(validOne));
        when(clientDetailsJdbc.getClientAccounts(accountTwo)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(validTwo));

        when(balanceDetailsService.getBalanceDetails(accountOne)).thenReturn(validBalanceDetailsDto);
        when(balanceDetailsService.getBalanceDetails(accountTwo)).thenReturn(validBalanceDetailsDto);

        List<SurgeClientDto> surgeClientDtos = surgeParisController.clientLeaderboard(accounts);

        // Then
        assertThat(surgeClientDtos.get(0).getAccountId(), is(accountOne));
        assertThat(surgeClientDtos.get(0).getAvailableToTrade(), is(100d));
        assertThat(surgeClientDtos.get(0).getAvailableToWithdraw(), is(100d));
        assertThat(surgeClientDtos.get(0).getClientName(), is(clientForename + " " + clientSurname));
    }
```

When I run my test it gets stuck in an infinite loop with no output. When I debug the code the last line to execute is

`CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).get();`

I have placed a breakpoint within `buildSurgeClientDto()` and tried running in debug mode again but the breakpoint is never triggered.

Why is this? Is there something special I have to do to test async `CompletableFutures`?

Comment: What `executor` is used for the test?

Comment: Ah... one I appear to have mocked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you mock `Executor`. It just never execute the task, so the test is just hang. What you can do is just use simple executor and inject it into your controller:

```
private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

instead of

```
@Mock
private Executor executor;
```

For your test it should work. You do not need to test `Executor` and `CompletableFuture` because it is part of JDK and well tested alredy.

But if you need mock executor you should mock or stub:

```
// CompletableFuture code:
executor.execute(new AsyncRun(dep, function));
```

otherwise the test will hang.